Ansys Maxwell 3D transient AlNiCo hysteresis simulation
I know this question has been asked many times, but sadly, none of the previous discussions I encountered appear to contain a definitive answer on how to make this work.
I have a very basic Maxwell 3D transient simulation setup with a cylindrical magnet and a coil wound around it. I apply a current pulse through the coil, which causes a strong magnetic field to be induced inside the magnet for a few microseconds. The field is sufficiently strong to reverse the magnetization of the cylinder. After the current is removed, I expect the cylinder to reverse its magnetization; however, it just returns to its original magnetization instead. The behavior of this simple simulation setup does not match the behavior of an actual prototype I assembled on the bench; the reason the prototype was built is to validate the correctness of Maxwell predictions but right now it is failing that.
The cylinder is made of LNG37 and the same material is selected in the simulation, taken from the RMxpert library; the material definition includes the correct BH curve spanning the first two quadrants, which should be sufficient to simulate the hysteresis effect according to what I read in the help and on the support forum.
Below are the plots of the solenoid current over time and the magnetic flux magnitude; the magnitude starts from 50 mT and goes back to that as expected, but what is unexpected is that the original magnetization direction is restored.

Can you please share any pointers what is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Does this simulation include eddy currents? Microseconds implies a mighty small magnet, or unusual construction (has the construction been modeled correctly?). Is the mesh size fine enough for this time scale?

@TimWilliams Eddy effects are disabled in this simulation; I can enable them but I assumed they have no relevance in this case. The magnet is only a 10x10 mm cylinder; the bench prototype can be fully magnetized by a 800 A 3 us pulse, in simulation both the duration and the magnitude of the pulse are longer. The mesh is configured to limit max segment length to 1.5 mm for the cylinder and 0.8 mm for the coil; I tried using finer settings to the same effect.

I might add that the coil makes 20 turns around the cylinder, so 800 A yields 16 kA*turns
